# How to block HTTP 302 redirection package by matching a specific string on Location?

Tags: firewall, iptables, http, tcp, tcpip

The HTTP response I want to block has:

```
Header

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.yxjiaodai.com/ad/?id=1023&url=http%3A//a1819.oadz.com/link/C/1819/3081547/dtMdon4l79FwsIo2JXEHqtdp5eQ_/p007/0/http%3A//www.womai.com/AdvRedirect.do%3Furi%3Dhttp%3A//www.womai.com/%26utm_source%3DtongyongG%26utm_medium%3Dtongyong%26utm_campaign%3Damg
Connection: close
```

I want to block all these responses by matching "yxjiaodai.com", my PC is windows 7, Router is linux based, it'd be ideal to stop those packages from passing Router, but dropping them at PC end is also acceptable.

Any idea?

Comment: if you wanna do it on pc then you may need a proxy or you can do it with a software firewall (most time they use a integrated proxy to do this) or you can try and have a look at the firewall on your router (most models of today have a builtin firewall)

Comment: A firewall on pc can only block the website "yxjiaodai.com" when redirection happens, it cannot stop the redirection. My router accept Iptables rules, I know it's powerful and been searching a lot, but couldn't find how to write the rule I need

Comment: you're right sorry for not beeing exact - with firewall i meant something like a Web Application Firewall (WAF) which has the Possibility to unpack IP Packets and is able to see from were the Packet really comes. - if you wanna do it the dirty way (i don't recomend that) you can add yxjiaodai.com to your hosts file on your pc and make it pointing to 127.0.0.1 so all the calls for yxjiaodai.com will not go to its ip but to your localhost (not really blocked but to prevent loading a malicious website it will be enough)